# Проблема с передачей json массива в функцию подключения

Tags: linux, c, json, сокет, bluetooth

Программа должна считать данные с bluetooth-устройства. Функция `SearchBT()` находит MAC-адреса устройств, отбирает MAC-адреса `rfcomm` устройств, пишет их в json массив и возвращает его из функции.

Сам вопрос состоит в том, что я не могу его передать в функцию подключения `ConnectionDev()`.
Еще мне что-то говорили про проверки строчки, помеченой `****`, но я не понял, на что именно проверять.

Также хочу услышать любую критику, начиная от присваивания правильных имен переменным, разнообразных проверок и так далее.

P.S. Прошу строго не судить, программист (если меня вообще можно так назвать) я начинающий.
Да, кстати, чтение по непонятной причине не проходит, команда для старта чтения правильная, сокет не блокируется, количество ожидаемых байтов правильное, пауза между отправкой команды и ожиданием приема данных достаточная...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <jansson_config.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
json_t *SearchBT();
int ConnectionDev();
void AutoInputPK();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //(json_array_get( SearchBT(), 1));
    json_t *Jarr2;
Jarr2 = json_array();
json_array_append(Jarr2,SearchBT());
//printf("\n2**---**%s*---**2", json_dumps(Jarr2, 0));
printf("jhgj");
ConnectionDev(Jarr2);
return (0);
}
```

//***_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_***__

```
int ConnectionDev(char *dest)//функция для подключения  устройства
{
    struct sockaddr_rc addr = {0};//мак устройства с рфкомм EC:FE:7E:11:85:1F
    int s, status, counter;
      printf("jhgj");
    AutoInputPK(dest);
    // выделить сокет
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
    // устанавливаем параметры соединения
    addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    str2ba(dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr);
    //char text[20]={0};
   **** status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    fcntl(s, F_SETFL, FNDELAY|fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0));
    counter = write(s, "wboam1\r", 8);
    //sleep(5);
    //counter  =read(s,text, 8);
    if (counter  > 0)
    {
    printf("\n received:\n [%s]", dest);
    }

    if (status == 0)
    {
        printf("\nYEP MF`s");
    }
    if (status < 0)
   {
        perror("uh oh");
   }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

//***_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_***

```
json_t *SearchBT() //Функция для поиска BT устройства с возвратом его мак адреса
{
    inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int max_rsp = 255, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, len = 8, flags;
    int i, socketRfcomm;
    char addrf[19] = {0};
    char *arrayMacaddr[20] = {0}; //сделать его динамическим
    socketRfcomm = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH; 
    ii = (inquiry_info *)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));
    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
    if (num_rsp < 0)
    {
        perror("hci_inquiry");
    }
    printf("all devices:");
    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++)
    {
        ba2str(&(ii + i)->bdaddr, addrf);
        arrayMacaddr[i] = strdup(addrf);
        printf("\n--[%s]", arrayMacaddr[i]);
    }  
    free(ii);
    close(socketRfcomm);
    json_t *asd, *as2;
    as2 = json_array();
    //цикл проверки мак адресов, с последующим удалением мак адресов левых устройств
    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++)
    {
        char str2 [8] = "EC:FE:7E";
        if (strncmp(arrayMacaddr[i], str2, 8) == 0)
        {
            asd = json_string(arrayMacaddr[i]);
            json_array_append(as2, asd);
            printf("\n**---**%s*---**", json_dumps(as2, 0));

        }
    }
    return (as2);
}
```

//***_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_***

```
void AutoInputPK(char *dest)   //функция автоматического ввода пин кода из симпл агент
{
    char *macAddrs = dest;
    char *cmdTemp = " bluez-simple-agent hci0 ";
    char cmd[50];
    sprintf(cmd, "%s%s", cmdTemp, macAddrs);
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = popen(cmd, "w");
    pclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: @kvars232, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectionDev(char *dest)` ожидает `char*`, а `Jarr2` имеет тип `json_t*`. И логически тоже не согласуется: `dest` это один адрес, а `Jarr2` двумерный (!) массив bdaddr. Неясно, зачем json объекты вообще здесь используются (злоупотребление ими как помощь в управлении памятью?).

В коде много других проблем. Я бы отладку от малого к большому использовал в данном случае: реализовать манусенький кусочек функциональности в виде отдельной функции, написать тесты для этой функции, чтобы была уверенность, что функция работает правильно хотя бы для каких-то значений, повторить для функций, её использующих.

Comment: jfs, поподробнее насчет других проблем.хотя бы парочку назови,если не лень=)Очень надо

Comment: и скажи объективный аргумент,почему тут не уместен json?

Comment: @kvars232: пока `char* dest` ошибка не исправлена, бессмысленно дальше говорить.